# Why do I get this error creating & returning a new struct?

Tags: c#, reference, events, struct, compiler-errors

I get an error when I compile this code:

```
using System;

public struct Vector2
{
    public event EventHandler trigger;

    public float X;
    public float Y;

    public Vector2 func()
    {
        Vector2 vector;
        vector.X = 1;
        vector.Y = 2;
        return vector;  // error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'vector'
    }
}
```

hi!

The compiler says: "Use of unassigned local variable 'vector'" and points to the return value. It looks to me that Vector2 become a reference type (without the event member it acts normally). What is happening?

Comment: Making structs with mutable members is risky.  Either use a class, or mark the fields as 'readonly'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C# you still need to 'new' a struct to call a constructor unless you are initializing **all** the fields.  You left EventHandler member 'trigger' unassigned.

Try either assigning to 'trigger' or using:

```
Vector2 vector = new Vector2()
```

The new object is **not** allocated on the heap, it is still allocated on the functions stack.

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(VS.71).aspx):

> When you create a struct object using
>   the new operator, it gets created and
>   the appropriate constructor is called.
>   Unlike classes, structs can be
>   instantiated without using the new
>   operator. **If you do not use new,** the
>   fields will remain unassigned and **the**
>   **object cannot be used** until all of the
>   fields are initialized.

Comment: You should be able to initialize it to null

Comment: I like to initialize my events to '= delegate { };', so I don't have to null-check when firing the event.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained ways round this, but I think it's worth mentioning the other big, big problem with your code: you have a mutable struct. Those are pretty much *always* a bad idea. This is bound to be just the first of many issues you'll run into if you keep it that way.

I *strongly* recommend that you either make it immutable or make it a class.

Comment: I'll emphatically second that - mutable structs *always* cause more pain than people expect.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Walker has a better response, since he started from the docs and then reasoned to the code (whereas I went the other way around).

If you compile the sample code with the trigger field commented out, and then run IlAsm to get the resulting MSIL, you'll see that there is no `initobj` opcode for the local variable vector.

The lack of `initobj` is fine when the `Vector2` structure only contains value types. They're just raw memory after all. However, if the `Vector2` structure also contains a reference, it must be initialized in order to prevent having an uninitialized object reference.

In order to avoid returning a partially unitialized object, you need to write to the `trigger` event handler explicitly, or initialize the whole object by way of a new operation. However, in no case is the structure turned into a reference type.